# How to delete contacts from Skype?

Tags: windows-10, skype

I'm using Skype 8.108 on a laptop running Windows 10 Pro and also Skype on a smartphone running iOS 16.5.1.

On both devices, when I click on Contacts a list of contacts comes up, even though the two lists are not the same.

On the iPhone, with some of the contacts there is an option to block or accept, but if I select block the person still shows up as a contact.

On the laptop, there is an option to block a contact, but I can't see any way to delete them.

So my question is this: on both devices, how can I delete contacts so that they don't show up? I don't want them "hidden", or "blocked" but still showing up. I want to delete them altogether. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you enter Settings, you should see your contacts in the Contacts section. You should then be able to right-click the contact you want to remove and select "Delete contact". Does this not work for you? Are you on the latest Skype version?

Comment: No, that didn't work for me. The "Delete contact" option wasn't there. But I eventually solved the problem by adding each contact first and then deleting it. I have latest versions of Skype on both devices. The iOS one I updated before posting here.

Comment: I too have this problem. On some contacts there is a "Delete contact" in the context menu of the contact, but on the one I want to delete, there is not. There is a "Block contact" option but I don't want to block, I want to delete. @tell I don't understand, what do you mean by adding the contact and then deleting it? It's already there, right? How are you readding it?